# I need a script to add rows or subrows if the value of the cell = X

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm a script newby and I'd like to automate the creation of rows underneath a cell every time the value of that certain cell is X

Whenever a Cell = WE, I'd like rows or subrows to be created underneath it with values: 
IT, ES, UK, NL, FR.

sample sheet can be found here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TbYsbqFHmpFOdmj8vgFY9jeGUI1O212sJGb3Umh2fWE/edit?usp=sharing

Can anyone help? Should I be using appendrow?

Many thanks, 
Nathalie

Answer (score 1):

Setup the onEdit trigger to run this function.  Put WE somewhere and rows will be added and required values will be set.

```
function addingRows(e) 
{
  var addA=[['IT'], ['ES'], ['UK'], ['NL'], ['FR']];
  var ss=e.source;
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col=e.range.getColumn();
  var row=e.range.getRow();
  if(e.value=='WE')
  {
    sh.insertRowsAfter(row,addA.length);
    sh.getRange(row+1,col,addA.length,addA[0].length).setValues(addA);
  }
}
```